# scale two matrices with scipy or sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I would like to scale a matrix X1 (by column), and then scale another matrix X2 with mean and standard deviations found when scaling X1.

As far as I know, sklearn does not return mean/variance when scaling a matrix. Is there an alternative approach without me implementing it?

For example:
X1

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

X2

```
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
```

replace `X2[i][j]` with `(X2[i][j] - mean[X1[:, i]]) / std[X1[:, i]]`

The scale function of sklearn preprocessing cannot be used because it does not return mean and variance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by scaling a matrix by a column and also for instance how X2 should look like?

Comment: scaling means normalizing each column of X1 with the mean of that column and its standard deviation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Standard Scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) from scikit learn handles this, and corner cases, pretty well.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X1)
output = scaler.transform(X2)
```

If necessary, you can access the means and standard deviations of the feature columns using

```
scaler.std_
scaler.mean_
```

You can also use the StandardScaler in a pipeline as preprocessing preceding an estimator.

Answer (score 0):

Both `.std()` and `.mean()` method accept `axis` parameter to calculate row wise/column wise statistics, the rest will be taken care of by boardcasting:

```
In [170]:

X1
Out[170]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
In [171]:

X2
Out[171]:
array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
In [172]:

(X2-X1.mean(0))/X1.std(0)
Out[172]:
array([[ 2.14330352,  2.14330352,  2.14330352,  2.14330352],
       [ 3.3680484 ,  3.3680484 ,  3.3680484 ,  3.3680484 ]])
```

Comment: the problem is that you have to manually handle cases where all values of a column are zero. I am trying to find a function that does that automatically

Comment: Not only when all values of a column ==0, as long as the values in that column are the same value, the variance will be 0 and the transformation will result in `+inf`. Not sure how you want to do in those cases.